# passing argument to python from shell script

Tags: python, sh

I have run through some similar questions but none seem to answer my doubt, I am trying to pass the argument to python script from my bash script. I don't see errors nor I get the required output. What am I doing wrong here?

python:

```
import os
import glob
import unicodecsv as csv
import pandas as pd
import codecs
import sys




OUTPUT_PATH=sys.argv[2] 


def createFolder(directory):
  # print('createFolder')
  try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            # print('createFolder')
            os.makedirs(directory)
            # print(directory)
  except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)
createFolder(OUTPUT_PATH + 'csv20_out/')
```

bash script:

```
INPUT_PATH='home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/csv64_in/'
OUTPUT_PATH='home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/'

cd /
cd home/pg/Documents/LMS/kanjiforbeginner/convertToYAML/


cd converts_csv642csv20
python csvFile.py $INPUT_PATH $OUTPUT_PATH
```

Should create a folder csv20_out

when I print OUTPUT_PATH, I get 'home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/'

Comment: What's the bash script you're using? Please provide that as well

Comment: Can you try with OUTPUT_PATH=sys.argv[2] instead ? If it doesn't work, try to print the content of OUTPUT_PATH to see what it is

Comment: I made a mistake, actually, it points to sys.argv [2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as the other commenters have pointed out, you need to use `argv[2]` instead of `argv[1]`
This is because in bash `argv[0]` is the python script being executed and `argv[1]` in your case becomes `'$INPUT_PATH'`

But, that won't solve your problem.
In your script, you need to remove the `'` surrounding `$INPUT_PATH` and `$OUTPUT_PATH` so that the last line becomes,
`python csvFile.py $INPUT_PATH $OUTPUT_PATH`

`'$INPUT_PATH'` sends the `string` `$INPUT_PATH` to your python script, whereas,

`$INPUT_PATH` sends `'home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/csv64_in/'`

or whatever value you choose to assign to `$INPUT_PATH`

And lastly, you need to change, the values of `$INPUT_PATH` and `$OUTPUT_PATH`
`INPUT_PATH='home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/csv64_in/'`
`OUTPUT_PATH='home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/'`

needs to become

`INPUT_PATH='/home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/csv64_in/'`
`OUTPUT_PATH='/home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/'`

The `/`  at the beginning gives the full path to the directory or file, if you didn't use the `/` then it becomes a relative path.

In your bash script, you're navigating folders using `cd` as a result, the folder

`'home/pg/Public/test_data/test0002_2files_to_1flow/csv_out'`

will get created under the directory,

`home/pg/Documents/LMS/kanjiforbeginner/convertToYAML/`

Adding the `/` at the beginning to `$INPUT_PATH` and `$OUTPUT_PATH` as shown before would ensure that your code:

- searches for input in the right directory
- creates the folder in the right directory

edit:

As Kim has suggested below, the last line in the script should be:

`python csvFile.py "$INPUT_PATH" "$OUTPUT_PATH"`

This is, in case `$INPUT_PATH` or `$OUTPUT_PATH` has spaces or special characters.

Comment: Your bash script should use "$INPUT_PATH" instead of $INPUT_PATH. If $INPUT_PATH includes spaces or other special character then $INPUT_PATH will expand into multiple arguments - which won't work as expected. "$INPUT_PATH" will expand into a single argument (which may include spaces or other special characters).

Answer (score 2):

The contents of sys.argv look like this:

```
['csvFile.py', 'inputPath', 'outputPath']
```

To get the outputPath you need to access sys.argv[2] in your case.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, the first argument is the name of the program itself—that is, the first thing specified on the command line (`whatever_name.py`).

So `argv[0]` is the program's name, `argv[1]` is your input path, and `argv[2]` is your output path.